# How to exclude concept pages from Solr search in Wordpress?

Tags: solr, wordpress, search-engine

Is there a way to tell the Solr Advanced Search plugin that my concept pages in Wordpress should not turn up in any search results?

Comment: Have you tried using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-exclude/) plugin?

Comment: No, not yet Rich. But I found out that the Solr plugin "listens" for status changes of posts. When they go to something else then "published" they are removed from the search index. But only, if the previous status was "published". I removed the last part from the plugin code (not good practice, I know) and now it all works as intended. Thanks for your suggestion though, I will definitely check it out.